# ArcInfo/ArcGIS Server Spatial Analyst not licensed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, spatial-analyst, error-000824

It might be me but there is something I’m not able to figure out.
I created a model in ArcGIS 10 that uses (among the others) “Extract by Mask” and “Zonal Statistics as Table” as functions (therefore Spatial Analyst extension) which runs smoothly on the desktop side. On this machine runs also ArcGIS Server (10) that I use to create a service that I want consume over the web.

Based on this thread, [How to check the ArcGIS server type](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/110329), I think I am running an Advance License because when I check the keycodes  file found in C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\License10.0\sysgen I find:

arcgisserver,100,[……],none, [……]

svradvanced,100, [……],none, [……]

arcsdeserver,100, [……],none, [……]

svrenterprise,100, [……],none, [……]

The server side should include the Spatial Analyst extension, right? (svradvanced) So, why do I get

```
ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
FAILED
```

When I try to consume the service?

I probably should mention that when I check ArcGIS Administrator I have two permanent licenses for ArcInfo Desktop and one permanent for Spatial Analyst

Comment: thanks cl3! even though you were first, I think I am going to accept the KHbma's one because more 
exhaustive. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: No problem. Hope you get everything sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the spatial analyst extension to run spatial analyst tools on Server.
You'd see an entry like:

> spatialserver,100,ecp.....

You can see the [license matrix here](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf). If you believe you should have spatial analyst based on what license/extensions you should have, but dont see it in that file, you should contact either Esri Customer Service or your Distributor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a license for the ArcGIS Desktop Spatial Analyst Extension, but not ArcGIS Spatial Analyst for Server. You will need to purchase one to use that functionality.